# Unable To Serialize Property, One to One Relation

Tags: java, jpa

Recently I created a new entity and a table to join one of my existing table/entity. But i guess i misconfigured and I am receiving this error:

```
[2023-04-06] [21:54:39,901] [SEVERE ] [10gjnye] [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller]: [Unable to serialize property 'contactFrequency' from com.policy.common.entities.PolicyDocument]
[2023-04-06] [21:54:39,901] [SEVERE ] [10gjnye] [org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller]: [Generating incomplete JSON]
[2023-04-06] [21:54:39,902] [INFO   ] [10gjnye] [com.gcdm.ms.utils.logging.filter.GcdmServiceLoggingFilter]: [MSG:#### SERVICE_EXIT: 90  * Server out-bound response on thread http-thread-pool::http-listener(4)
90 RESP < 500
```

And throws 500.

**MAIN ENTITY**

```
package com.policy.common.entities;

import com.policy.common.entities.enums.PolicyDocumentStatus;
import com.policy.common.util.logging.PmToStringStyle;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.DateDeserializers;
import com.sun.istack.Nullable;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;


@Entity
@Table(name = "policy_document")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = PolicyDocument.findPolicyDocumentByNameCountryAndVersion,
query = "SELECT p FROM PolicyDocument AS p WHERE p.name = :name and p.country = :country and p.majorVersion = :majorVersion and p.minorVersion = :minorVersion"),
@NamedQuery(name = PolicyDocument.findPolicyDocumentByNameAndCountry,
query = "SELECT p FROM PolicyDocument AS p WHERE p.name = :name and p.country = :country"),
@NamedQuery(name = PolicyDocument.findAllPolicySearchDocuments,
query = "SELECT NEW com.policy.common.entities.PolicySearchDocument(p.id, p.name, p.validFrom, p.country, " +
"p.majorVersion, p.minorVersion, p.status) FROM PolicyDocument AS p"),
@NamedQuery(name = PolicyDocument.findPolicySearchDocumentsNotArchived,
query = "SELECT NEW com.policy.common.entities.PolicySearchDocument(p.id, p.name, p.validFrom, p.country, " +
"p.majorVersion, p.minorVersion, p.status) FROM PolicyDocument AS p WHERE p.status != :archived"),
@NamedQuery(name = PolicyDocument.findPolicyDocumentNotArchivedById,
query = "SELECT p FROM PolicyDocument AS p WHERE p.id = :id AND p.status != :archived")})
@XmlRootElement
public class PolicyDocument implements DocumentMetadata, Serializable {

public static final String findPolicyDocumentByNameCountryAndVersion = "findPolicyDocumentByNameCountryAndVersion";
public static final String findPolicyDocumentByNameAndCountry = "findPolicyDocumentByNameAndCountry";
public static final String findAllPolicyDocuments = "findAllPolicyDocuments";
public static final String findAllPolicySearchDocuments = "findAllPolicySearchDocuments";
public static final String findPolicySearchDocumentsNotArchived = "findPolicySearchDocumentsNotArchived";
public static final String findPolicyDocumentNotArchivedById = "findPolicyDocumentNotArchivedById";

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "policy_document_id_seq", sequenceName = "policy_document_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "policy_document_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
private Long id;

/**
* The policy name (sometimes called policy id)
*/
@Column(name = "name")
protected String name;

/**
* Date from which the policy document is valid
*/
@Column(name = "valid_from")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonDeserialize(using = DateDeserializers.CalendarDeserializer.class)
protected Calendar validFrom;

/**
* A policy document is identified by PolicyName, MajorVersion, MinorVersion and country.
* Here is the two digit ISO country code
*/
@Column(name = "country")
protected String country;

/**
* Major version number
*/
@Column(name = "major_version")
protected Integer majorVersion;

/**
* Minor version number
*/
@Column(name = "minor_version")
protected Integer minorVersion;

/**
* currently unused integer field
*/
@Column(name = "data_controller")
protected Integer dataController;

/**
* A short description of the PolicyDocument
*/
@Column(name = "description")
protected String description;

/**
* List of all textblocks which contains the language dependend texts and usage definitions
*/
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "policy_document_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
protected List<TextBlock> textBlocks = new ArrayList<>();

/**
* Currently unused field
*/
@Column(name = "primarytext")
private String primaryText;

/**
* Currently unused field
*/
@Column(name = "secondarytext")
private String secondaryText;

/**
* Contact frequency days for marketing frequency rule
*/
@OneToOne( mappedBy ="policyDocument", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Nullable
protected ContactFrequency contactFrequency;

/**
* Dummy for compatibility
*/
@Transient
protected List<TouchpointLink> touchpointLinks = new ArrayList<>();

/**
* Status of the document DRAFT, APPROVED, SUBMITTED ...
*/
@JsonIgnore
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "status")
protected PolicyDocumentStatus status;

@Transient // detached per default to avoid having to move large CLOBs all the time
private List<EncodedPolicyDocument> encodedPolicyDocuments = new ArrayList<>();

/**
* @deprecated only use in JPA, never in tests! In tests, use builders instead. They will assign negative IDs to keep the ID space clean
*/
@Deprecated // Warning: only use in JPA, never in tests! In tests, use builders instead. They will assign negative IDs to keep the ID space clean
public PolicyDocument() {
// default constructor is needed when returning as entity, as per the JAX-RS spec
}

@Override
public Long getId() {
return id;
}

@Override
public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
return name;
}

@Override
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

@Override
public Calendar getValidFrom() {
return validFrom;
}

@Override
public void setValidFrom(Calendar validFrom) {
this.validFrom = validFrom;
}

@Override
public String getCountry() {
return country;
}

@Override
public void setCountry(String country) {
this.country = country;
}

@Override
public Integer getMajorVersion() {
return majorVersion;
}

@Override
public void setMajorVersion(Integer majorVersion) {
this.majorVersion = majorVersion;
}

@Override
public Integer getMinorVersion() {
return minorVersion;
}

@Override
public void setMinorVersion(Integer minorVersion) {
this.minorVersion = minorVersion;
}

@Override
public Integer getDataController() {
return dataController;
}

@Override
public void setDataController(Integer dataController) {
this.dataController = dataController;
}

@Override
public String getDescription() {
return description;
}

@Override
public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

@Override
public List<TextBlock> getTextBlocks() {
return textBlocks;
}

@Override
public void setTextBlocks(List<TextBlock> textBlocks) {
this.textBlocks = textBlocks;
}

@Override
public String getPrimaryText() {
return primaryText;
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryText(String primaryText) {
this.primaryText = primaryText;
}

@Override
public String getSecondaryText() {
return secondaryText;
}

@Override
public void setSecondaryText(String secondaryText) {
this.secondaryText = secondaryText;
}

@Override
public PolicyDocumentStatus getStatus() {
return status;
}

@Override
public void setStatus(PolicyDocumentStatus status) {
this.status = status;
}

@Override
public List<EncodedPolicyDocument> getEncodedPolicyDocuments() {
return encodedPolicyDocuments; //NOSONAR
}

@Override
public void setEncodedPolicyDocuments(List<EncodedPolicyDocument> encodedPolicyDocuments) {
this.encodedPolicyDocuments = encodedPolicyDocuments; //NOSONAR
}

@Override
public ContactFrequency getContactFrequency() {
return contactFrequency;
}

@Override
public void setContactFrequency(ContactFrequency contactFrequency) {
this.contactFrequency = contactFrequency;
}

public List<TouchpointLink> getTouchpointLinks() {
return touchpointLinks;
}

public void setTouchpointLinks(List<TouchpointLink> touchpointLinks) {
this.touchpointLinks = touchpointLinks;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return new ToStringBuilder(this, PmToStringStyle.multiLineInstance(0))
.append("id", getId())
.append("name", getName())
.append("validFrom", getValidFrom())
.append("country", getCountry())
.append("majorVersion", getMajorVersion())
.append("minorVersion", getMinorVersion())
.append("status", getStatus())
.append("description", getDescription())
.append("textBlocks", getTextBlocks())
.append("dataController", getDataController())
.append("contactFrequency", getContactFrequency())
.toString();
}
}
```

**NEW ENTITY**

```
package com.policy.common.entities;

import com.policy.common.util.logging.PmToStringStyle;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "contact_frequency")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = ContactFrequency.findContactFrequencyByPolicyDocumentId,
query = "SELECT cf FROM ContactFrequency as cf WHERE cf.policyDocument = :policyDocument")
})
@XmlRootElement
public class ContactFrequency implements Serializable{

public static final String findContactFrequencyByPolicyDocumentId = "findContactFrequencyByPolicyDocumentId";

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "contact_frequency_id_seq", sequenceName = "contact_frequency_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "contact_frequency_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "frequency_days")
private Integer frequencyDays;

@OneToOne(cascade =CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "policy_document_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
private PolicyDocument policyDocument;


public ContactFrequency(Long id, Integer frequencyDays, PolicyDocument policyDocument) {
this.id = id;
this.frequencyDays = frequencyDays;
this.policyDocument = policyDocument;
}

public ContactFrequency() {
}

public Long getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
this.id = id;
}

public PolicyDocument getPolicyDocument() {
return policyDocument;
}

public void setPolicyDocument(PolicyDocument policyDocument) {
this.policyDocument = policyDocument;
}

public Integer getFrequencyDays() {
return frequencyDays;
}

public void setFrequencyDays(Integer frequencyDays) {
this.frequencyDays = frequencyDays;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return new ToStringBuilder(this, PmToStringStyle.multiLineInstance(0))
.append("id", getId())
.append("policyDocument", getPolicyDocument())
.append("frequencyDays", getFrequencyDays())
.toString();
}

}
```

**THE API CAUSES ERROR**

```
@Override
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public PolicyDocument findById(@PathParam("id") Long id) throws NotFoundAppException {
PolicyDocument policyDocument = policyFinder.retrievePolicyDocument(id);
ContactFrequency contactFrequency = searchContactFrequency.findContactFrequencyByDocumentId(policyDocument);
ContactFrequencyDto contactFrequencyDto = searchContactFrequency.toFrequencyDto(contactFrequency);
if (contactFrequencyDto.getFrequencyDays() != null) {
contactFrequencyDto.setId(null);
pmLogger.info("Policy Document's contact frequency is null: " + contactFrequencyDto);
}
policyDocument.getContactFrequency().setId(contactFrequencyDto.getId());
policyDocument.getContactFrequency().setFrequencyDays(contactFrequencyDto.getFrequencyDays());
pmLogger.info("Policy Document with contactFrequency: " + policyDocument);

if (PolicyDocumentStatus.DRAFT.equals(policyDocument.getStatus())
&& (currentEnvironmentUserRoles.hasAnyRole(Roles.Use_PM2_POLICY_APPROVER)
&& !currentEnvironmentUserRoles.hasAnyRole(Roles.Use_PM2_POLICY_USER, Roles.Use_PM2_POLICY_ADMIN, Roles.Use_PM2_GLOBAL_ADMIN))) {
throw new NotFoundAppException("You do not have the permission to access the document");
}
return policyDocument;
}
```

**THE QUERY FOR CONTACT FREQUENCY**

```
package com.policy.admin.search.control;

import com.policy.common.entities.ContactFrequency;
import com.policy.common.entities.ContactFrequencyDto;
import com.policy.common.entities.PolicyDocument;
import com.policy.common.logging.Loggable;
import com.policy.common.logging.PmLogger;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

@Loggable
@Stateless
public class SearchContactFrequency {

@PersistenceContext(
unitName = "policy"
)
EntityManager em;
@Inject
PmLogger pmLogger;

public SearchContactFrequency(){

}

public ContactFrequency findContactFrequencyByDocumentId(PolicyDocument policyDocument){
TypedQuery<ContactFrequency> query = em.createNamedQuery("findContactFrequencyByPolicyDocumentId", ContactFrequency.class);
query.setParameter("policyDocument", policyDocument);
List<ContactFrequency> results = query.getResultList();
if (results.isEmpty()){
pmLogger.info("NULL VALUE");
return null;
}
pmLogger.info("Contact Frequency by given policy document id: " + results.get(0).getFrequencyDays());
return results.get(0);
}

public ContactFrequencyDto toFrequencyDto(ContactFrequency contactFrequency) {
ContactFrequencyDto contactFrequencyDto = new ContactFrequencyDto();
contactFrequencyDto.setId(contactFrequency.getId());
contactFrequencyDto.setFrequencyDays(contactFrequencyDto.getFrequencyDays());
pmLogger.info("Mapping entity to dto completed successfully: " + contactFrequencyDto);
return contactFrequencyDto;
}

}
```

Whenever I try to retrieve a document by a given id, I face this issue.
Since I don't want to get rid of contactFrequency, I cant use @Jsonbtransient.
Have any clue guys?

Comment: The policy document contains a contact frequency and the contact frequency contains a back reference to the  policy document? How do you expect the json to look? Create a dto without the back reference.

Comment: Hi @daniu, thanks for your answer. Do you mean dto for policy document? Because I already have a dto for contact frequency. I was mapping contact frequency to dto and setting the dto parameters to policy document parameters. But contact frequency's policy document reference is still going to be there. How I can get rid of it? btw sorry to be dumb and make you angry

Comment: You've got a circular reference which will cause a stack overflow as your serializer recursively goes through a PolicyDocument to covert it to JSON. You have to tell it how to handle the circular reference caused by PolicyDocument.contactFrequency and ContactFrequency.policyDocument referencing each other. JSONIgnore on one side is the most common, but then you have to reset the reference yourself at times. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Hi @Chris thank you for your helpful comment. My problem was solved when I applied the first solution in the document you sent.